# Barcode Scanner Device with android SDK

Tags: android, device, barcode

I want to integrate barcode scanner in my android app. But i am not getting any company which provide barcode scanner device with Android SDK. So that i can Configure this device to my Android App.
Please help me guys if some one have any info about my query?

Comment: You want to use the  mobile as barcode scanner ?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides the [Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview) which detects barcodes in real-time, on device, in any orientation. It can also detect multiple barcodes at once.

It reads the following barcode formats:

> **1D barcodes:** EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
>
> **2D barcodes:** QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC

Checkout demo app available on github [Barcode-scanner](https://github.com/1priyank1/Barcode-scanner)

Comment: is this has been introduced recently ?

Comment: @ShadyAtef No, this has been introduced more than year ago.

Comment: problem with this approach is that you must have `internet connection` for the first time launch of the app so that dependencies can be downloaded. Also it is not open source.